# UIImageView goes black color and make all other images black

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash, uiimageview

I added recently snapped images to my table view ..

And when i press any row of the tableview and navigate to another view and come back to my view then the image is converted to half black and when i repeat the process again then the whole image converted to black and some other images of tableview also goes black.

I am storing the images to document directory.

Is there anything stupid think which i am doing ?

Comment: post some code dude like cellforrowatindexpath and your viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear

Comment: Can you give me your skype id....?

Comment: Based on your description, I'd say you have a bug in your code.

Comment: you can talk me on gtalk my email address is on my profile. my skype id is imrahulvyas tell me urs I will send you invitation.I need to download skype.

Comment: @Rahul Vyas  : The profile does not show email to others ,that is shown to user only.
My skypeid is ranjeet.cssoft please accept my request

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillAppear, do this

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [yourTableViewName reloadData];
}
```

if not worked well, its better to use Lazy Image Loading feature..